# Query from one to many relation database to datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, blazor

I am just starting with SQL and trying to get my first example working. I have two tables with a one-to-many relation:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am executing following command through API `ProjectsController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<Project> projects = 
         await _context.Projects.Include(d => d.Customer).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(projects);
}
```

I am getting my

```
private IEnumerable<Project> ProjectsList { get; set; } = new List<Project>();
```

on the razor page, with

```
this.ProjectsList = await this.HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Project>>("api/Projects");
```

I have checked data structure of `ProjectsList` with debugger and it looks fine.

However: the Razor page table (two columns "Project name" and "Customer name"):

```
<Table DataSource="ProjectsList" TItem="Project">
  <Column TData="string"
          Title="Name"
          @bind-Field="context.Name"
          SorterCompare="@((a,b)=> string.Compare(a,b))"
          SortDirections="new[] { SortDirection.Descending }"
          Filterable />
    <Column TData="string"
    @bind-Field="context.Customer.CompanyName"
    SorterCompare="@((a,b)=> string.Compare(a,b))"
    SortDirections="new[] { SortDirection.Descending }"
    Filterable />
</Table>
```

I get an exception of object not set to instance of object. I guess this is because of `context.Customer.CompanyName` where `Customer` is not initialized?

First of all I have a question should I redo my `Project` model and add there additional column of type string `CompanyName` or there is some other way to get data displayed on razor page?

In case if... I should add additional column into `Project.cs` how to query data using linq in there?

Comment: In the future you may want to use `var` to shorten your code by omitting the variable type and `using` to shorten the namespace.

Comment: Could you try changing it to `context.Customer?.CompanyName` instead? And can you check where the null is?

Comment: @HiFo - A question.  Have you considered that you are building your Application Logic - the relationship between Customers and Projects - into your data layer?  I know EF allows, almost encourages this, but the more complex you build relationships the more difficult it becomes to (expletive not typed) figure out what is going wrong.  The alternative is to build these relationships into your Core Application layer.  The complexity doesn't change, but it's all C# code.  You can debug it, and Mock it for testing!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I am currently just practicing, but yes, I need to investigate Architecture of my application in more detail. I have seen a lot of examples now of architecture examples, so it is a little bit hard for me to pick one as I don't yet understand the benefits of each one. Currently I have only Client, Server and Shared.

Comment: @HiFo.  There are many competing alternatives out there!  I've built a Blazor solution and template based on what are know as "Clean" design principles here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.  It will at least give you a Blazor-centric starting point.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis where should I store classes like ApplicationUser.cs and ApplicationRole.cs for example in your model?

Comment: A good question . If they are application specific then in the application core.  If organisation specific, in a separate Auth library organised on the same principles - Auth.Core namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, try the following, and if you get an error, post its text here:

`public Customer Customer { get; set; } = new Customer {};`

Comment: If he's using EF Core, I don't think you can have a Project without Customer. Guid cannot be null, and if OP has Nullable Ref enabled, the reference cannot be null as well. But if it's indeed the problem, I believe you shouldn't do that, since looks like the code is being used server-side for EF Core as well.